# Rails App - jQuery Dynamic Select Ignoring Spaces?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

REQUEST form has many CATEGORIES and CATEGORY has many PRODUCTS.  Select the Category to populate the Product selection list.  Here's the jQuery:

```
jQuery ->
    $('#request_product_id').parent().hide()
    products = $('#request_product_id').html()
    console.log(products)
    $('#request_category_id').change ->
        category = $('#request_category_id :selected').text()
        options = $(products).filter("optgroup[label=#{category}]").html()
        console.log(options)
        if options
            $('#request_product_id').html(options)
            $('#request_product_id').parent().show()
        else
            $('#request_product_id').empty()
            $('#request_product_id').parent().hide()
```

Here's the form partial:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category_id, "Select a Category:" %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.sorted, :id, :name, :include_blank => true ) %>
  </div>

  <!--  BASED ON CATEGORY SELECTED ABOVE, LOAD CORRESPONDING PRODUCTS BELOW -->

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :product_id, "Select a Product/Service:" %>
    <%= f.grouped_collection_select :product_id, Category.sorted, :products, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
  </div>
```

This works great if the Category Name has no space in it, but if it does, the Product list does not load.  For instance:  category.name = "Software" or "Personnel" - loads all the software or personnel products just fine.  But if category.name = "Application Development" or "Business Objects Report", nothing loads.

How come?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try `options = $(products).filter("optgroup[label='#{category}']").html()` in your jQuery.

Comment: Hah - thanks!  I just got it, too.  (I will approve your answer when it allows me to!)

Comment: @KatieM, :) very nice only a few seconds difference!

Comment: Hey, now that I have you - can you help with loading a static text field that shows the product.description when the Product is selected?

Comment: @KatieM, I can try.  Since that's a different question, I suggest you ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I added single quotes around the #category:

```
options = $(products).filter("optgroup[label='#{category}']").html()
```

Thanks for letting me talk it out!  :)